# Character is not valid in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The dollar character is underlined with red in my Visual Studio VB.NET project saying:

> character is not valid

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: First, you should not post images of code. Second, if you move your mouse over the character underlined you should see the reason.

Comment: It says character is not valid, but i don't know why?

This is my first post..sorry..xD

Comment: You probably are using an older version of visual studio or vb, string interpolation only works on VB14 and up/VS2015 and up I believe. If you use an older version of visual studio, then you have to specifically use a newer compiler to take advantage of those features.

Comment: Visual-Studio 2010 probably has no idea what is that char before a string

Comment: Ok, thanks to all, i will try on vs2017..

Comment: i know its not the question...depending on how big N is, you might want to use a string builder and only assign the text property once

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to upgrade an older ASP.NET application you may need to install the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform NuGet package.

You can find out by going to the Build menu in Visual Studio and if *ASP.NET Compilation* -> *Enable latest C# and VB language features...* is present then that's the reason.

You can click that and it will install the latest version of the package for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an older version of Visual Basic.

You should instead try the following

```
txtpronadji.Text &= i & "     "

txtpronadji.Text &= num
```

Comment: Never use + to concatenate strings. Should be `txtpronadji.Text = txtpronadji.Text & i.ToString & "        "`

Comment: @DavidWilson Note that you can use `&=` to append in VB.

Comment: @DavidWilson sorry, switching from c# to vb.net to answer this question, you are right

Comment: @Craig Ah yes forgot about that. Thanks.